# unable to call a function on click Event of an image in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have defined a Variable containing the Image in a java script file

```
 var route ='<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/mwewcja1j/146117012724825.png" alt="route" id="routeimg" onclick="myFunction()" style="width:50px;height:35px;">';
 function myFunction{alert("hello")}
```

Error myFunction is not defined.

or

```
 var route ='<img src="http://s31.postimg.org/mwewcja1j/146117012724825.png" alt="route" id="routeimg" style="width:50px;height:35px;">';
document.getElementById("routeimg").onclick= "alert("hello")";

Error :routeimg is not defined
```

I have googled for all posts of this type & replicated the Exact Procedure but nothing helped me out

Comment: How does the image actually get added to the page? Neither of your examples shows how that `route` variable is used. Assuming you do create an actual element from that string, your `myFunction()` would have to be in the global scope in order to be accessible from an inline `onclick` attribute. Also, why the "java" tag? JavaScript != Java.

Comment: Yes that myFunction() is in the Global Scope

Answer (score 2):

Your function has incorrect syntax.  It's missing the parentheses:

```
function myFunction(){
    alert("hello")
}
```

For this to work, your `route` has to be added to the DOM of course.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure why you posted that JavaScript.

Comment: var content= '<div>'+route+'</div>';

      var info1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      info1.setContent(content)

//Var Route is used in the Infowindow on a Google Map

Comment: That's great, it sounds like you have a plan, do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

The second code snippet will fail for a different reason. Whilst parsing the HTML document converts a tag attribute value of `onclick="alert('hello')"` into a HTML event handler function of form

```
function(event){ onclick_attriute_text_from_HTML_source };
```

and adds it as the onclick property of the HTMLelement created for the tag in the DOM, you can't set the attribute to text in code. It must be set to a function object instead. E.G.

```
document.getElementById("routeimg").onclick= function(){alert("hello")";};
```

As before, you must have added the element to the DOM first.